# Chebyshev's Inequality Produces Result with Negative Value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to solve the following problem:

The radius of a circle is a random variable X, with the mean value $\mu_x=10$, and variance $\sigma^2=5$. Compute a lower bound on the probability that the radius lies between 8 and 12 using Chebyshev's inequality.

According to Chebyshev's inequality:

$$P[|X-\mu_X| \le k] > 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{k^2} \tag{1}$$

This is equivalent to:

$$P[\mu_X - k \le X \le \mu_X + k] > 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{k^2} \tag{2}$$

As we need to compute $P[8 \le X \le 12]$, therefore, comparing $P[\mu_X - k \le X \le \mu_X + k]$ and $P[8 \le X \le 12]$,

$$\mu_X - k = 8 \tag{3}$$
$$\mu_X + k = 12 \tag{4}$$

As $\mu_X=10$, therefore, $k=2$. Using these values in (2) produces the following:

$$P[8 \le X \le 12]> 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{k^2} = 1-\frac{5}{4} \tag{5}$$

$$P[8 \le X \le 12]> -\frac{1}{4} \tag{6}$$

This results in a negative value of the bound on the probability. What could be wrong? I would much appreciate any help with this.

Comment: $P(8\leq X \leq 12)>-\frac{1}{4}$ is trivial but true. It means, that you cannot get any further general information of the event $8\leq X \leq 12$ with Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: If $X$ has a unimodal continuous distribution then [I think you may be able to say](http://www.se16.info/hgb/cheb2.htm#Unimodal2tailed) $P(8\leq X \leq 12) \ge \frac{256}{729}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, nothing has gone wrong. Chebyshev's inequality doesn't tell you anything if what you're looking at is within one standard deviation of the mean -- and in this case, it is.

A more illuminating example might be to consider what actually happens. Suppose that $$P(X=10-\sqrt{5})=\frac12=P(X=10+\sqrt{5})$$
The standard deviation of this data is, of course, $\sqrt{5}$, (with variance $5$), but $P[8\le X\le 12]=0.$ Of course, if the distribution were uniform or normal, then the probability will be greater, but this example demonstrates that Chebyshev, by itself, is absolutely useless in this scenario.

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason that Chebyshev is useless within a single standard deviation? The line of reasoning seems very interessting

Comment: @TheCoolDrop - The two-sided Chebyshev inequality is useless within a single standard deviation for the reason illustrated in this example: it is possible to have all the probability exactly $1$ standard deviation away from the mean

Comment: @hdighfan Thank you for the answer and very good example.